# How can I drop all indexes at once using Cypher in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

Is there a way to do  something like `DROP INDEX ON *` that would delete all indexes?

If I have a larger number of indexes it can take some time to delete them one by one. Is there some query that can loop through exiting indexes and delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this by simply using Cypher at the moment. There is [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/365) in the Memgraph repository for this feature.